# How to plot the forecasted values against actual values observed later in R?

Tags: r, time-series, data-visualization

We used the R library `forecast` to make predictions for the next 24 hours. We have the following:

```
fore_cast=forecast.tbats(model,h=24,level=90)
fore_cast
         Point Forecast    Lo 90     Hi 90
5.380952       6270.778 5389.089  7296.643
5.386905       5458.096 4557.375  6536.743
5.392857       5219.995 4248.967  6412.814
5.398810       5187.102 4126.390  6520.328
```

Now we have 2 problems:

- We need 'time' (in hour e.g. 01,23,19 etc) instead of 'point'.
- We wish to plot the trendline against time showing the actual observed
  values against these predicted values. We have loaded actual observed
  values from a CSV file.

We tried:

```
actual_data = read.csv('actualdata.csv')
plot(actual_data,fore_cast)
```

Doesn't work, and using `plot(actual_data)` just shows some points in a straight line instead of curved trendline.

EDIT:

Sample output of `fore_cast` from `dput`:

```
structure(list(model = structure(list(lambda = 0.000438881055939422, 
    alpha = 0.65694875480321, beta = -0.0983972877836753, damping.parameter = 0.800419363290521, 
    gamma.one.values = c(-0.00150031474145603, -0.00124696854910294
    ), gamma.two.values = c(0.0023600487982342, -0.002465549595849
    ), ar.coefficients = NULL, ma.coefficients = NULL, likelihood = 13202.294346586, 
    optim.return.code = 0L, variance = 0.00855092137349485, AIC = 13258.294346586, 
    parameters = structure(list(vect = c(0.000438881055939422, 
    0.65694875480321, 0.800419363290521, -0.0983972877836753, 
    -0.00150031474145603, -0.00124696854910294, 0.0023600487982342, 
    -0.002465549595849), control = structure(list(use.beta = TRUE, 
        use.box.cox = TRUE, use.damping = TRUE, length.gamma = 4L, 
        p = 0, q = 0), .Names = c("use.beta", "use.box.cox", 
    "use.damping", "length.gamma", "p", "q"))), .Names = c("vect", 
    "control")), seed.states = structure(c(7.44188559667267, 
    0.00357069100887873, -0.0664300680553579, 0.0229067500159256, 
    0.00460111570469819, -0.00772324725408007, -0.000610110386029883, 
    0.00568378752162509, -0.0084050648066819, -0.0324093004247092, 
    -0.000720936399990958, -0.00705790547321605, -0.00738992950838566, 
    0.00180424326179638, -0.00107745502434416, 0.00242014705705761, 
    -0.01824679745657, 0.0123019701003545, -0.0245935735677402, 
    0.0181321397860132), .Dim = c(20L, 1L)), fitted.values = structure(c(1598.57443298879, 
    1435.74973092922, 1397.92464316794, 1296.90202189518, 1440.3201303663, 
    1544.11695101118, 1777.97079874181, 1766.50571671645, 1925.27360388028, 
    1863.26963233038, 1773.08363764691, 1887.26580055295, 1887.48006609474, 
    1841.66200850472, 1991.90290660363, 2233.04775631848, 2081.30246965768, 
    1872.12639817609, 1899.38583561568, 2213.43437455052, 2214.00832820531, 
    1745.36311914995, 1678.67975050944, 1502.35472259274, 1512.27350460399, 
    1456.14165844166, 1464.3803467642, 1517.99443293857, 1484.54280422369, 
    1382.37041287489, 1452.43700910726, 1545.16934543365, 1440.50974319508, 
    1475.59742668699, 1544.88546424501, 1790.95280713647, 1916.4267023671, 
    1928.72804180587, 1819.15839770808, 1916.43079357329, 1836.80043977753, 
    1720.25638746452, 1730.03629161412, 1614.6048115754, 1599.23641723244, 
    1635.86950932066, 1543.46360784778, 1641.35066985679, 1608.60556151299, 
    1651.47649465456, 1475.15006990464, 1403.67294742438, 1507.58932406857, 
    1666.3170708439, 1696.06132797576, 1543.32187293056, 1704.58043626911, 
    1914.72424191575, 2109.33624862625, 2092.98934458578, 2222.13355258602, 
    2084.68677709368, 1962.9230489947, 2045.61547393981, 2140.30565941261, 
    2097.46130996426, 2126.07936955385, 2226.18935508502, 2269.54492801286, 
    2300.37314952852, 2398.48786829541, 2303.31270702723, 2332.74139979969, 
    2146.51487558643, 2101.27480789243, 2111.61910899422, 2053.57840714969, 
    2046.56606362537, 2073.82870990658, 2094.88831798868, 2334.85185938782, 
    2541.72156227893, 2502.36031483721, 2398.12240784327, 2266.35832277135, 
    2151.05248890962, 2266.88803633019, 2366.19453856405, 2399.97570044332, 
    2341.74959623409, 2144.33465155869, 2102.91952061083, 2214.48622101851, 
    2179.48115699957, 2288.28092735955, 2224.55218736155, 2195.1506809087, 
    2163.94619334319, 2161.41843642149, 2134.75060670667, 2138.77895768654, 
    2142.84680080931, 2258.55072549978, 2297.90237035988, 2314.94197015208, 
    2300.99928929609, 2277.39754662665, 2291.06980363364, 2487.04257346235, 
    2381.05768214413, 2509.40078456481, 2657.61336243367, 2528.65026804303, 
    2434.2722174014, 2366.04811963942, 2270.6647135766, 2231.33965004538, 
    2376.51043520344, 2249.42861599343, 2193.98771109322, 2252.12327312365, 
    2210.76969838623, 2180.50451255189, 2221.92898123682, 2537.84678083006, 
    2329.57350097532, 2252.82349908982, 2143.92033677754, 2092.3142840022, 
    2084.70304624685, 2111.18929138546, 2160.05383108999, 2280.94409931504, 
    2118.22029344747, 2214.65738250204, 2269.05911898631, 2084.26658709038, 
    2016.04764576402, 2095.57091797435, 2161.07354463394, 2427.77607700887, 
    2333.91103594967, 2234.23838054763, 2250.71557301013, 2186.97925802073, 
    2129.51096829218, 2115.40228652934, 2094.89231085691, 2086.41044567131, 
    2180.94542608489, 2105.38187642016, 2459.45788915933, 2292.36325639374, 
    2410.75372754831, 2375.56640249604, 2491.11938114866, 2470.51372278037, 
    2464.95765202085, 2600.85929020727, 2709.48518695182, 2779.77558137814, 
    2518.29927341458, 2344.06621605191, 2391.56719713269, 2368.68842788795, 
    2199.93530349068, 2113.92970206565, 2458.96718445444, 3121.97852988865, 
    2559.40932439262, 2331.12829078836, 2238.54586985577, 2241.91440620202, 
    2225.29804576634, 2154.14147781021, 2060.57980596908, 2037.30100544426, 
    2215.93410789353, 2364.42668160056, 2518.72871618042, 2537.34279365294, 
    2473.76096855791, 2623.63387707374, 2589.08335304697, 2577.0563838788, 
    2349.53279218826, 2305.52193868551, 2232.63712180453, 2167.50003597208, 
    2320.23187534213, 2281.86365949586, 2281.21119271599, 2323.2014703372, 
    2185.94404743238, 2140.21863271207, 2011.67723856012, 1966.52063119589, 
    2002.67344212857, 1952.41101080662, 1988.37461163105, 2126.75137749373, 
    2239.14722292367, 2320.98046489603, 2444.91847853015, 2431.69548763034, 
    2514.73820659393, 2505.85249387343, 2888.19773974179, 2853.20690693738, 
    2502.20865871069, 2524.56894781003, 2659.52271740553, 2615.9025930681, 
    2923.69327019152, 2754.76074569658, 2784.59488335761, 2874.24378479002, 
    2683.41908597168, 2733.83011888159, 2774.1325162997, 2906.41593326865, 
    2726.06821502751, 2460.21579967528, 2450.8035097605, 2547.39389733175, 
    2625.60323572861, 2827.94083526683, 2971.92012845614, 3042.90981987278, 
    2835.00811374845, 2846.98066660519, 2871.21876763166, 2901.99696373824, 
    2627.47532996657, 2583.75084300313, 2602.68041642846, 2632.8054092953, 
    2667.85374690972, 2639.10586730146, 2466.95799545022, 2381.06823502402, 
    2531.32611053776, 2407.14812148706, 2342.75701798463, 2401.73791085847, 
    2365.50645844524, 2404.50408575777, 2452.57343738519, 2613.15332739214, 
    2665.50965844576, 2723.8237337447, 2915.09266385617, 2890.17498445896, 
    2853.6278331055, 2868.1228183545, 2917.07803535669, 2876.59409770233, 
    2577.82035337979, 2581.91435020803, 2520.20342021937, 2603.37973251208, 
    2536.03988578365, 2510.83398648802, 2472.80606784857, 2425.51212342113, 
    2442.02863541673, 2465.73405821711, 2384.42988766816, 2555.51500549788, 
    2737.77091706275, 2425.00224845814, 2460.17325671183, 2639.16650619329, 
    2816.37024420397, 2755.69999167982, 2802.64991688288, 2685.12803367301, 
    2521.77568128564, 2500.99980614696, 2620.41659854805, 2529.25134423133, 
    2590.14804885984, 2318.80485234464, 2341.88940012276, 2460.21008281205, 
    2513.70688167177, 2437.71670675479, 2383.29782281743, 2499.36244454453, 
    2472.98602901478, 2491.10649022417, 2350.1405559119, 2362.78308814045, 
    2431.3911847573, 2321.15216823049, 2355.74203614213, 2429.60523843166, 
    2355.61947983433, 2346.3751018515, 2453.82214513707, 2542.98125962684, 
    2342.43364707529, 2302.17741211575, 2388.93541944219, 2435.41878657221, ....
```

Sample output from dput for actual observed values:

```
structure(list(index12 = c(6297.416944, 5406.865556, 4718.355556, 
5304.729167, 4968.014722, 5081.130833, 5544.955, 4655.009444, 
4269.023056, 4346.588333, 4511.455833, 5102.57, 4818.673333, 
4862.343056, 4785.176667, 5385.005278, 6469.080833, 7166.025278, 
7010.708333, 511.114167)), .Names = "index12", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data using `dput` so that we can try to provide a solution.

Comment: I have imported data to files using 'dput'. Do you want me to attach the files here you mean?

Comment: Just copy and paste subsamples of your data into your question. See the following post on [creating R examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for some pointers.

Comment: Paste into your question the actual output of `dput`. We don't need all the data, just small samples of the forcasted data and the actual data.

Comment: I have included the required output in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `Point` is unusual in spite of hour unit data. I think you failed to make a `model`.

Here is my example:

```
actual_data <- structure(list(index12 = c(6297.416944, 5406.865556, 4718.355556, 
                           5304.729167, 4968.014722, 5081.130833, 5544.955, 4655.009444, 
                           4269.023056, 4346.588333, 4511.455833, 5102.57, 4818.673333, 
                           4862.343056, 4785.176667, 5385.005278, 6469.080833, 7166.025278, 
                           7010.708333, 511.114167)), 
                         .Names = "index12", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))

# I suppose that actual_data was taken per hour.
num_actual <- as.numeric(actual_data[,1])
model <- bats(num_actual)
fore_cast <- forecast(model, h=24, level=90)

fore_cast   # Point is from 21 to 44 because of length(actual_data)=20 and demanding predictions for the next 24 hours
#    Point Forecast    Lo 90    Hi 90
# 21       5063.207 2902.187 7224.226
# 22       5108.114 2946.988 7269.241
#  :
# 44       5108.114 2944.629 7271.600

# plot() has forecast method. It draws actual_data and prediction, and paints Lo90-Hi90.    
plot(fore_cast, main="")
```

[image]